# Got UK Visitor Visa refusal due to Visa Officer overlooking my documents. Need advice

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Hope you all are doing well!

I have received a UK visitor refusal because the visa officer said that I only have 122 PKR (£0.5) in my Checking account. Completely overlooking the fact that I had given another bank statement of my Savings Account which had more than £13000.

How should I address this? Should I reapply? Should I contact a lawyer? What is the fastest and cheapest way of getting this fixed keeping in mind I live in Pakistan.

And if I reapply, do I need to send all the other supporting documents again?

Please see refusal below:

[image]

Comment: You might want to review [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and compare it with your situation.

Comment: I don't think the officer overlooked your savings account (if it is the one with the United Bank they referred to)... But you have to show that you have easy access to the savings at any time, which is not necessarily given, depending on the banks' policies.

Comment: @xngtng The savings account bank statement showed regular withdrawals and deposits. How else do I show I have easy access?

Answer (score 2):

There is no appeal process for standard visitor visa. Since its easier and cheaper to submit the application again, with same information, but with a cover letter to point to the mistake made. The cover letter should be to the point that this is the case.

You can consult an immigration lawyer in UK (Not anyone in Pakistan). They are qualified to give you advise. But it will involve significant cost.

Details: https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser

Also, [please look into this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), to clarify your doubts regarding the bank statements.

Comment: I see. Do I need to add all the supporting documents again or just the document that caused refusal?

Comment: @taq12345 Consider it like a fresh application. Fix the flaws in documentation. Include a cover to highlight this issue, in addition to all other documents.

Comment: @taq12345 Can you elaborate the nature of account? Why are you maintaining a separate account? Is it solely in your name? Did you submit the statement for the second account?

Comment: I only move my monthly salary from my salary account to my savings account so I get interest on it. It's a very basic thing most people do. And yes, I had attached statements for both accounts.

Comment: @taq12345 Then elaborate all these and apply again. I think ECO made an obvious mistake in this case. Also, try not transferring this month, so that some amount is in that account.

Comment: got it. Thanks!